# IIS Rewrite exclude rule by HTTP method

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Can I add a condition to exclude an IIS URL Rewrite rule if the request type is `POST`? I was not able to find it anywhere in the documentation.

I don't want to lower-case my URL if the HTTP method is `POST`.

```xml
 <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is filtering the input `{REQUEST_METHOD}`, negating every request matching `POST`, like:

```xml
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```